# why redis mset function does not have expiry or TTL option

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

In terms of functionality, i can work around this limitation, but want to understand whether there an architectural reason why it is not supported out of the box?

PS: (this is not a question). 
I have work around e.g.: call EXPIRE individually for each key which I am setting with `mset`. I don't know if that is any better than calling `set` individually for each key (in a pipeline if transaction does not matter), as `set` allows to specify TTL.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, i did some benchmarks and calling set individually for each key is always faster. By approximately 15% for 2 keys and approximately 7% for 200000 keys. The benchmark was made with Go though and Redis calls were parallelized.